# Comparing two values in the same column SQL

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I am running the following query in a Java servlet:

 `SELECT * FROM table order by updated desc limit 2;` 
I want to compare the two most recent values in the same column to determine if they are different. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Just run that query, access the result set, and compare the two values.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How do I do that if the values are in the same column?

Comment: Not my downvote.  Just read a good JDBC tutorial, like [this one](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/).  This is a very basic question.  Your query will return two values for that column.  All you have to do is compare them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one idea ...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table 
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,value INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1,5),(2,6),(3,6);

SELECT i 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT id
            , CASE WHEN @prev=value THEN @i:='same' ELSE @i:='different' END i
            , @prev:=value prev 
         FROM my_table
            , ( SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=null) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY id 
     ) x 
 ORDER 
    BY id DESC 
 LIMIT 1;
+------+
| i    |
+------+
| same |
+------+
```